# Do I need to have python venv set up to install and use apps like pywal and wpgtk

Tags: python, virtualenv

Basically the title. I have one set up and have installed pywal and wpgtk using '`pip install .`' But it's installing the apps into `~/.venv/bin` (as opposed to .local/bin) and ~/.venv/bin is not in my path unless the virtual env is activated.
I'm confused on how I can set this up properly. Right now I've added ~/.venv/bin to my path to get these apps to work.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Ubuntu 23.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two way to run a Python script relying on Python modules installed within the venv:

1. activate the venv and then run the Python script
2. Call the Python interpreter from the venv with its full path and give the full path to the file execute.

On the latter: let's assume your venv is **~/myvenv** and your script is at **~/myvenv/my_cool_script.py**. Calling `~/myvenv/bin/python3 ~/myvenv/my_cool_script.py` will run the script with all modules accessable installed within **myvenv**.

In case you are only looking to run Python executables installed within a venv, you may want to take a look at [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/).

Comment: I've decided to use pipx and pywal installed fine but wpgtk produced an error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'

I have all the dependencies (afaik).